is there a way to remove default style from button in android?
I have button in android studio xml file and its not changing shape and color when I change it
i dont wanna make my own styles
how it looks
here is my code:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragments.PlantsListFragment">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:background="#1F1F27">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/spaces"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_square"
            android:backgroundTint="#1C2F33" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>

also here is my rounded_square.xml file if needed:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape android:shape="rectangle" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#1C2F33" />
    <corners android:radius="30dp" />
</shape>

I wanted this button to be color "#1C2F33" and I want it to have rounded corners

Don't use Button, use AppCompatButton instead, then apply the background shape drawable to it. You also don't need a background tint, since the color has already been specified in the shape drawable.
 <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_square" />

Also some more context.
You don't remove the style, you replace it.
By default every control in Android inherits from the theme passed down from its Application (the launchTheme you specify in your manifest) or the Activity's Theme (also specified in manifest).
Controls can have their own styles, you just have to create one then apply it to your control. That theme will automatically replace the theme passed down from its parent context (activity/application).
If you're using Material themes, then remember to only use AppCompat Controls. AppCompat allows much easier customisation, rather than the Base Controls (such as Button).
